# Recover damaged git repository

Tags: git

I'm on Win 10 and I have a number of uncommitted changes on my local workstation.  I have been using GitHub Desktop.

In an attempt to get a 3rd party library to work, thinking the issue was spaces in my path to my project, I changed the folder names to remove spaces in the path to my project. Did not help and I changed back to original paths.  However, I think this caused a hiccup with GIT.  When I open GitHub Desktop I get the message "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree".

Running MINGW64 bash and doing a little research I determined that the env variables GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_DIR were missing.  I reset them and now I get:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    .gitignore
    deleted:    Deploy.txt
    deleted:    Dialogs/copypickdlg.cpp
    deleted:    Dialogs/copypickdlg.h
    deleted:    Dialogs/popup.cpp
    deleted:    Dialogs/popup.h
    deleted:    Dialogs/prefdlg.cpp
    deleted:    Dialogs/prefdlg.h
    deleted:    Dialogs/workspacedlg.cpp
    deleted:    Dialogs/workspacedlg.h
    deleted:    Dialogs/zoomdlg.cpp

    ... all my files

    deleted:    xmp.txt
    deleted:    zoomdlg.ui

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    COMMIT_EDITMSG
    FETCH_HEAD
    HEAD
    ORIG_HEAD
    config
    description
    hooks/
    index
    info/
    logs/
    objects/
    packed-refs
    refs/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So, if I understand this correctly I need to add the files back:

```
$ git add-*.*
```

I'm a git novice so I'd like confirmation I am correct before proceeding.

Comment: According to that output, git is confused and thinks the `.git` subdirectory is actually your working directory.

Comment: I was wondering about that.  There is a .config file in my home directory but no repository.  I tried setting GIT_DIR to my home directory but that did not work, so I set it to the same as my project working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to set GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_DIR at all.
The [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-codegitdircode) is clear:

> The `.git` location may be auto-discovered

Its default location is just under the root folder of your repo.

Unset those variables and do a git status in a Git bash session, in order to check the repo is still recognized

```
cd /path/to/root/folder/of/repo
ls .git
git status
```